# AirPrint no longer works since new router

Tags: ipad, wifi, printing, airprint

Trying to print from iPad, worked fine until we got upgraded from 60 MB/s to 100 MB/s; new router is dual 2.4 GHz & 5 GHz tried both, updated printers firmware.

Curiously we can still print from within 'brother' app; can print pdfs photos webpages etc... it's just AirPrint with iOS apps like mail, safari that doesn't work: "No air printer found".

Router ports are all on but greyed out. Printer is a Brother HL-5450DN, iOS is 9.3.5 and the router is Arris DG1670

printer/apple/internet support can't figure it out, any help would be greatly appreciated!